# XAMPP MySQL suddenly stopped working for no visible reason

Tags: mysql, xampp

I've been searching since last night. I could not find anyone else having my problem.

I start MySQL, wait about 3-5 seconds. It shuts down unexpectedly.

I checked the error log but nothing abnormal. I tried to copy MySQL backup folder to data folder and it solved the problem but my tables are removed so not a good solution. What should I do ?!

log :

```
2021-09-30  9:56:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-09-30  9:56:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-09-30  9:56:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-09-30  9:56:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-09-30  9:56:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-09-30  9:56:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-09-30  9:56:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 1259779; transaction id 4016
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-09-30  9:56:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix and retrieve your db data you can try the following steps:

1. Copy `mysqldata` folder to: `mysqldata_copy`
2. Delet all files (**apart from folders!**) in `mysqldata` folder.
3. Run MariaDB/MySQL via XAMPP
4. The files would be self-generated in our folder.
5. Copy file: `mysqldata_kopia/ibdata1` and paste it into `mysqldata` folder (it will override the file).
6. Restart MariaDB/MySQL via XAMPP.
7. Done.

Comment: Ok, It got working but I get this error in phpmyadmin: SELECT command denied to user 'pma'@'localhost' for table 'pma__table_uiprefs'

Comment: found out that I need to add this code : `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';`